# How do I get a warning after logging in, depending on the user's attributes?

Tags: keycloak

How can I display a warning page after a user logs in, depending on the user's attributes?

I added the following script (execution) to the browser flow.

```
function authenticate(context) {
    if (!user.getFirstAttribute("someAttribute")) {
        context.challenge(context.form().setInfo("you don't have some attribute", null).createInfoPage());
        return;
    }
    context.success();
}
```

If the conditions are met, the warning page will be displayed, but the user will not become logged in state and will be presented with a login form each time they access it.

I want to display the warning only once and enable users to use each service.

Answer (score 1):

It should be part of your login flow. So you can implement custom **conditional authenticator** that may show additional page before login process is finished, depending on some user attribute value.
See implementation guidelines in [docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_auth_spi).

UPD. If you want to show that warning only once, you should add some mark to user account (possibly another attribute). Also check out Required Action SPI, maybe it will fit better for your case.

Answer (score 0):

For the time being, I was able to solve it with the following script.

```
function authenticate(context) {
    if (!user.getFirstAttribute("someAttribute")) {
        authenticationSession.setRedirectUri("http://keycloak.example.com/warning.html");
    }
    context.success();
}
```

Supplement.

If you want to have a warning page in keycloak, you can do it as follows...

```
function authenticate(context) {
    if (!user.getFirstAttribute("someAttribute")) {
        var path = context.form().createForm("resouces-path.ftl").getEntity().trim().replace(/^\/auth/,'');
        authenticationSession.setRedirectUri(path+"/warning.html");
    }
    context.success();
}
```

It is the contents of the above "resouces-path.ftl".

```
${url.resourcesPath}
```